# Removing MouseListener when something happens

Tags: java, swing, methods, overriding, mouse-listeners

In the game that I'm currently making I have three different `mousePressed` methods, one for single fire, one for automatic fire and one for melee attacks. Because the one for automatic fire uses a swing `Timer` I can override it in the other `mousePressed` methods by using `timer.stop();` in them.

But the single fire `mousePressed` calls the `fire()` method directly so I can't override it in any way from the other `mousePressed`. The code below shows the method for the fireing (bullet is a `ArrayList`).

```
public void fire(){
    if(!power.getChainsaw()){
        bullet.add(new Bullet(x, y));
    }
}
```

When the player gets a melee weapon I therefor need to remove the `MouseListener` for the single fireing. I have tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
removeMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        player.mousePressed2(e);
    }   
)};
```

I add the single fire and melee `MouseListener` in the exact same way as this. This is hwo the acctual `mousePressed` methods lok like.
public void mousePressed2(MouseEvent e){

```
if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)){
        timer.stop();
        fire();
    }
}

public void mousePressed3(MouseEvent e){
    if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)){
        timer.stop();
    }
}
```

`mousePressed2` is the single fire method and `mousePressed3` is the melee method

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
removeMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        player.mousePressed2(e);
    }   
)};
```

Look at what you are doing here. You are removing an instance of `MouseAdapter` created in place. This means that a new instance of mouse adapter will be created and then removed, but because the specific listener instance is not binded to any button, nothing will happen.

Pass the correct listener to the `removeMouseListener` method and it will work.

```
MouseAdapter myListener = new MouseAdapter() {
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        player.mousePressed2(e);
   } 
};
someButton.addMouseListener(myListener);
// then when you want to remove it, use the same referenece.
someButton.removeMouseListener(myListener);
```